# Running action queries in access db

Tags: runtime, ms-access-2010, ado

I have access 2010 runtime installed on my system. I cannot run action queries through my c++ program using ADO. Is it possible to stop disabled mode while opening a connection to the database? Is there any ways to stop disable mode through code using ADO?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: Are you saying that you cannot run action queries from C++ *while the Access runtime has the database open*, or that you cannot run action queries from C++ *at all*? While you're at it, please tell us the actual error message you receive (if any).